# Problem after updating plugins

Tags: plugins, admin, errors, updates

So today i updated my plugins, everything went smoothly, but later i found out that my website is messed up. All the custom taxonomies are gone, then one of my plugin disappear somehow. I tried to reinstall the plugin, but i got this error

```
Installing Plugin: WordPress SEO by Yoast 2.2.1
Downloading install package from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wordpress-seo.2.2.1.zip…

Unpacking the package…

Installing the plugin…

Destination folder already exists. /customers/b/1/f/yahya98.com/httpd.www/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/

Plugin install failed.
```

Well, i haven't tried deleting the folder manually from FTP, but i don't want to make a wrong step, there's more than 40 post in my blog, it's a big problem if i have to re-write meta description and the other things for every post... so i post it here in case there's an alternate way.

Comment: You can still back up the plugin folder AND the database before trying to delete/update it.

Comment: There is problem with the file access please change the permission of the "wordpress-seo" dir from FTP or rename the "wordpress-seo" to "wordpress-seo-old" or something like that and then try to install

Comment: @Mitul will i lost all my settings if i do that? and the permission is fine, the other plugins have same permission but have no problem with that

Comment: No all the data will be there you will not loss single data i will give detail document in ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with the "wordpress-seo" permission so please following steps.

There are two way
1) Upload from the wp-admin
    Step 1 -> Change the "wordpress-seo" permission or rename the "wordpress-seo" plugin to another
    Step 2 -> If you have change the permission then just upgrade the plugin and if you have rename the plugin dir then you need to follow the install new plugin steps.

2) Change the file using FTP:

Step 1 -> Take backup of your old plugin
   Step 2 -> change the plugin name or delete from the server
   Step 3 -> Upload the plugin via FTP

It will not remove the data.

Comment: Thanks, i was afraid that it would reset all my settings.

Comment: If will. Not reset the options because all data are stored in database